# Binary to decimal algorithm in c giving strange results

Tags: c, binary

Hi i'm fairly new to c but for a program I'm writing I need to convert binary strings to decimal numbers. here is my current code:

```
int BinaryToInt(char *binaryString)
{
    int decimal = 0;
    int len = strlen(binaryString);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {

        if(binaryString[i] == '1')
            decimal += 2^((len - 1) - i);
        printf("i is %i and dec is %i and the char is %c but the length is %i\n", i, decimal, binaryString[i], len);
    }
    return decimal;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("%i", BinaryToInt("10000000"));
}
```

and here is the output:

```
i is 0 and dec is 5 and the char is 1 but the length is 8
i is 1 and dec is 5 and the char is 0 but the length is 8
i is 2 and dec is 5 and the char is 0 but the length is 8
i is 3 and dec is 5 and the char is 0 but the length is 8
i is 4 and dec is 5 and the char is 0 but the length is 8
i is 5 and dec is 5 and the char is 0 but the length is 8
i is 6 and dec is 5 and the char is 0 but the length is 8
i is 7 and dec is 5 and the char is 0 but the length is 8
5
```

I'm confused as to why this doesn't work, all help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Ps: I'm used to java so at the moment C just makes me cry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `^` operator is not for exponentiation, but is instead the bitwise XOR operator.

If you want to raise a number to a power of 2, use the left shift operator `<<` to shift the value `1` by the exponent in question.

```
decimal += 1 << ((len - 1) - i);
```

Answer (score 2):

The trick is the same as with any number base: for each incoming digit, multiply the accumulator by the number base and add the digit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int BinaryToInt(char *binaryString)
{
    int decimal = 0;
    int len = strlen(binaryString);
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        decimal = decimal * 2 + binaryString[i] - '0';
    }
    return decimal;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%d", BinaryToInt("10000000"));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
128
```

Comment: I'm not sure how the + binaryString[i] works. Does c automatically convert it to an integer?

Comment: The `char` type is promoted to `int` before the calculation. The `'0'` is subtracted as ASCII or EBCDIC or other character coding adjustment. Numeral encodings are required to be consecutive. That might have been clearer if written as `decimal * 2 + (binaryString[i] - '0')`

Comment: What compiler and standard do you use? cause running this with gcc c99 gives me 64 as an answer

Comment: Please check your code: did you put `BinaryToInt("1000000")`?